# Force Android Studio to use gradle 4.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I have downloaded a previous version of Android Studio (3.0.1) since I must use the android gradle plugin version 3.0.1 and gradle 4.1.

The code, and the other modules it depends on, were written using Android Studio 3.2, kotlin 1.3.10 and gradle version 4.10.2

When I try to synchronize the project with the older version of Android Studio (3.0.1) or running `gradlew assembleDebug` it says the minimum gradle version is 4.6 even though the gradle wrapper version is 4.1 and the gradle plugin version is 3.0.1. The kotlin version for all dependencies was set on 1.2.41

This is the error:

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.1.
>
> Please fix the project's Gradle settings. Fix Gradle wrapper and
>   re-import project Gradle settings

How can I compile such project using older the older version?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use newer gradle wrapper and plugin in order to compile your project, if you want to use AS 3.2. So there is two options for you - upgrade wrapper and plugin, or downgrade AS, plugin, wrapper and kotlin in all dependencies.

Comment: I am sorry but you misread my question. It states that I am opening the project with the older Android Studio version and the older gradle version, I am editing the question because I just tried that but with Kotlin downgraded to 1.2.41 and still doesn't sync

Comment: Do you also downgrade wrapper and all other stuff in modules? Maybe you missed one?

Comment: After that you should also check that gradle-wrapper.properties point to correct distribution url in each module. And then try to invalidate cache and restart AS.

Comment: Yes, already did all that and AS still insists on using gradle 4.6